# Avoid reloading head scripts when page load via Ajax

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, load

I have a main page via a div. Many page are load into div via "load" function in jQuery.

When page loaded all script in head of page is load.

Is there a way to prevent scripts from being reloaded when the script is already loaded?

Comment: Please be more specific: what server-side technology are you using ASP.NET MVC or Web Forms.

Comment: i use asp.net webform and my script are load in head of per page.

Comment: Are you using a master page?

Comment: no. i create tab dynamic and load pages into div via "load"

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: this architecture is wrong and should not be used. My response is only to address the OP's specific problem)

Try wrapping the head area of your pages in an if statement, which checks whether the request is ajax or not:

```
<%if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest){%>

<head>
   ...
</head>

<%}%>
```

**Update**

In response to OP's comment - Add a querystring parameter to every ajax request that happens after the first one. Use some JavaScript for that. Then change the if statement to check for that parameter:

```
<%if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["secondTime"]){%>

<head>
   ...
</head>

<%}%>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but script must load for first page loading any way(load via ajax or other way). but when page is load for second time ,Scripts should not be loaded. because in second load script Interference is created